# Tried printing "Hello World!", got error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java

I tried printing, "Hello World!", in Java, (code below), but got an error,

`

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

`

Here is the error

> 

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Java is version 1.8.0_351
Javac is version 17.0.4

I tried making a simple Hello World script but that didn't work

Comment: If you compile with java17, you need to run it with at least java 17.

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled with a different version of Java compiler and you are now running with a different version of Java runtime. The runtime must not be lower than the Java compiler.

Comment: The JRE and the compiler do not have to be the same so long as the JRE version is the most recent of the two.

Comment: @vsfDawg, you are right